# php command missing from ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, 18.04, php, php-cli

I have Ubuntu 18.04 bionic installed on my machine.
It came pre-installed from the manufacturer ( System 76 ) with:

- apache2 2.4.29
- php 7.2
- mysql 5.7 ( both server and client )
- nodejs 8:10
- git 2.17.1

I am trying to install **CiviCRM**, which requires that the commands `php`, `node`, `mysql`, `mysqldump`, be executable from the shell command line (I use `bash`).

Searching, I could not find executables with these names or symlinks to them anywhere in the usual places ( e.g `/usr/bin`, `/bin` ).  If I knew the path names of the executables above I could set my PATH to include their directories. Does anybody have any insight into this?

Comment: What you got when you for example run `php -v` in terminal? `which` command your friend. The binaries, mentioned by you, are "included" in default PATH.

Comment: Hello Joseph and welcome to **askubuntu!** Please try to improve your post in better way.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the pre-installed packages where broken. The solution was to reinstall all of the packages with:
**sudo apt-get --reinstall install packagename**